# Build several index.html files (one per language) from a common template?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have a React app where I need to internationalise the open graph meta properties and title, description and noscript tags in `index.html`. For an open graph crawler like the one they use on slack, facebook, linkedIn etc. to see these, the server needs to supply an `index.html` where all of these properties are set to the correct internationalised string when the client accesses the link. So using a client based framework like Helmet is out of the question.

1. Goal 1: I would like Vite to use a common template to produce three versions of index.html: one for each language. Each `index_lng.html` should use the same javascript bundle.

I have looked into writing my own Vite plugin for this, but it seems I can only do a 1 to 1 mapping of my index.html template.

2. Goal 2: I would also like to configure the dev server to serve the correct `index_lng.html` file based on a query parameter in the URL. So if I send someone a link to `myapp.com?lng=de`, the dev server should respond with `index_de.html`.

Is it possible to achieve these two things with Vite? Any pointers would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.